# How obtain the word or words into char in a String

Tags: java, string, char

I need to obtain the words framed with a symbols `« »` in a String:

**Example**:

```
String phrase = "«User» of the «application»";

String words[] = phrase.indexOf("«") + phrase.indexOf("»")

words[0] = "User";
words[1] = "application";
```

The problem is, that solution obtains only the first word: "User" and I need all the words framed...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String phrase = "«User» of the «application»";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("«\\w+»");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(phrase);
        while (m.find()) {
            list.add(m.group().replaceAll("«", "").replaceAll("»", ""));
        }
        String words[] = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[User, application]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String phrase = "«User» of the «application»";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("«\\w+»");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(phrase);
    while (m.find()) {
        String text = m.group().substring(1,m.group().length()-1);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```